# Question about intervals and infima/suprema

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

Let $L(E)$ be the set of lower bounds of a set $E$ and $(S, \le)$ a partially ordered set.  For each $s \in S$, let

$$
\langle s] := \{x \in S  \mid x \le s\}
$$

and

$$
[s\rangle := \{x \in S \mid x \ge s\}.
$$

I want to prove that for $E \subseteq S$, one has $L(E) = \langle s]$ for some $s \in S$ $\iff$ inf $E$ exists (i.e., $L(E) = \langle$inf $E]$).

I was wondering if the following is a valid argument:  **If $e =$ inf $E$ exists, then $L(E)$ contains no $\gamma > e$.  Thus, every $\alpha$ $\le e$ is in $L(E)$, which means that, by definition of $\langle s]$, $L(E) = \langle e]$ = $\langle$inf $E]$.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $L(E)$ is the set of lower bounds of $E$?

Comment: Sorry about that...yes I do!  Thanks, I will change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** By definition of infimum, $\text{inf}(E)=\text{max}\{s\in S: \forall e\in E, s\le e\ \}=\text{max}(L(E)),$ if it exists. Saying $L(E)=\left<s\right]$ for some $s$ is just saying that $L(E)$ has a unique greatest element.

Comment: That seems crystal clear to me, thanks!  However, is that rigorous enough of an explanation?  I think I am saying basically the same thing in my argument (in more rigorous language?), but I am not really sure, which isn't a good thing :-).

Comment: I think your proof relies on the fact that $S$ is linearly ordered (maximal elements coincide with greatest elements),  which it need not be. But you can argue as follows: $\inf(E)$ exists $\Longleftrightarrow L(E)$ has a greatest element $e$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ there is an $e\in S$ such that for all $s\in L(E), s\le e\Longleftrightarrow$ there is an $e\in S$ such that $L(E)=\left<e\right]$.

Comment: Hmmm...well I follow your logic (it is indeed so clear, thanks for giving me an example of cogent argumentation!) pretty darn smoothly.  Except, I can't really understand how my proof presumes totality for the given relation (in question) on $S$.  Thanks a ton already for through the logic - sorry if I am being stubborn!

Comment: You go from "every $\alpha \le e$ is in $L(E)$" and "no $\alpha \gt e$ is in $L(E)$" to "$L(E)=\left<e\right]$", which is only a true implication if $S$ is linearly ordered. For example, let $S=\{a,b,c,d\}$ be ordered by $a\ge c, a\ge d, b\ge c, b\ge d$ (draw a diagram to better understand this partial ordering). Let $E=\{a,b\}$, then $L(E)=\{c,d\}$ contains all $\alpha\le c$ ($c$ is the only such $\alpha$) and contains no $\alpha\gt c$ ($a,b$ are the only such $\alpha$, but $L(E)\neq \left<c\right]=\{c\}$. Of course $E$ has no infimum.

Comment: Oh, oh, oh I see...and now it seems like a very obvious thing.  Okay, thank you very much for explaining that to me...and everything else of course - sorry for my stubbornness!